# pointer being freed was not allocated error when deleting reference

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm writing a very simple tic-tac-toe game that uses a variable board size

These are the bits of code that directly handle memory:

```
game_board::game_board(int size) {
    _size = size;
    _board = (player**) std::malloc(_size * sizeof(player *));

    // fill the memory block with memory blocks, making it a 2D array
    for (int c = 0; c < _size; c++)
        _board[c] = (player*) std::malloc(_size * sizeof(player));

    // fill the entire matrix with player::NONE values
    for (int c = 0; c < _size; c++)
        for (int r = 0; r < _size; r++)
            _board[c][r] = player::NONE;
}

game_board::~game_board() {
    if (_board) std::free(_board);
}
```

However when I try to call the destructor Xcode throws me the following error:

```
tic-tac-toe-cpp(63230,0x7fff77fa5310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100200000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I also tried to use a `template` to set the array size, but the compiler wouldn't let me do it using variables, which lead me to use `malloc` instead.

What's going on here, and how can I fix it?

**NOTE**

Doing this:

```
game_board::~game_board() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) 
      std::free(_board[i]);  
    if (_board) std::free(_board);
}
```

Makes the program fail in the same way (except the program halts in the loop instead), that's why there wasn't a for loop in the destructor above, because I thought it was the cause of the problem...

Comment: You called `malloc` so you need to call `free`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I get the same error regardless

Comment: It could be that you are copying or assigning `game_board` without suitable copy constructors/assignemnt operators. I suggest using a well-behaved class (e.g. `std::vector` or `std::vector`-based) to handle the data storage and avoid this kind of tedious problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought of that too, but given the fact that the array doesn't change size after it's initialised, a vector seems overkill

Comment: Do you have other constructors in `game_board`? Also do you ever copy it?

Comment: You have destructor. Consider having `copy constructor` and `assignment operator` or make them private. Can you show the usage?

Comment: You allocate with `std::malloc` but free with `free`. Maybe use `std::free` instead.

Comment: Also you leak memory because you don't free the `_board` contents (players)

Comment: A vector-based solution would be easy to implement with very few lines of code. But you can always implement your own, it you think ~8 bytes is too much overhead.

Comment: It might be an idea to add error checking on those allocation calls. If one of them fails, you will get an error when you try to free it.

Comment: You should post a complete working example, otherwise answering this question is walking in the dark (and I'm voting now to close it as off-topic)

Comment: @AntonSavin `_board[c][r] = player::NONE;` doesn't crash means possibly all was good. Moreover if `_board` is `NULL`(`malloc` failed), there should be no error in free. (Also he is (redundantly)checking for `NULL` before freeing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
game_board::~game_board() {
    for (int c = 0; c < _size; c++)
        std::free(_board[c]);
    std::free(_board);
}
```

But prefer `std::vector`

Moreover you should implement `copy constructor` and `assignment operator` or disable those by making private.

**EDIT** From you code you are calling `obj.~game_board();` explicitly. Which causes destructor to be called twice and double free. Please don't write that. Destructor for local variables are called automatically and you don't need to call that explicitly.

[Live working code](http://ideone.com/gyJU9p)

Comment: This is what I tried at first, throws the exact same error

Comment: Do you have copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: why are those so important?

Comment: If you don't have those, compiler would provide default copy constructor with behavior of shallow copy. This can cause double free if you pass `game_board` object to some function or make a copy or return from somewhere causing the error mentioned by you. Suggestion would be to use `stl container`. You can use valgrind to debug current code memory usage.

Comment: funny thing is that I don't use `game_board` in any other context all I do in my main right now is call the constructor followed by the destructor

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Can you fork and change [this code](http://ideone.com/AisLTQ) to make the usage more similar to yours? (It may or may not fail on ideone)

Comment: when working with pointers of it, does `delete` also call the deconstructor? because calling both the deconstructor and delete results in the same issue

Comment: yes `delete` calls the destructor. You should almost never call the destructor by yourself.

Comment: Good to know, a different source I saw said that it DIDN'T call the destructor, hence the confusion.

Comment: It will happen if you use (not recommended in C++) `free` to free the object.